# Fill each slot in a grid layout with fixed size text views whose size doesn't change with content

Tags: java, android, android-studio, textview, grid-layout

Whenever i use "xyz.setText("blah blah")" the text view expands according to the size of the content.App is crashing constantly.please help
(gridlayout=2X2)

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/rowzcolz"
android:text="TextView"
android:gravity="fill"
app:layout_rowWeight="1"
android:textAlignment="center"
app:layout_columnWeight="1"/>
<TextView
android:id="@+id/rowzcolo"
android:textAlignment="center"
android:text="TextView"
android:gravity="fill"
app:layout_rowWeight="1"
app:layout_columnWeight="1"/>
<TextView
android:id="@+id/rowocolz"
android:textAlignment="center"
android:text="TextView"
android:gravity="fill"
app:layout_rowWeight="1"
app:layout_columnWeight="1" />
<TextView
 android:id="@+id/rowocolo"
android:textAlignment="center"
android:gravity="fill"
app:layout_rowWeight="1"
app:layout_columnWeight="1"
android:text="TextView"/>
</android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Q: the text view expands according to the size of the content**

> A: Might occur if you have given the width as `match_parent` or `wrap_content` try giving a fixed width and setting `maxLines` to restrict the text. Specify the width and height apart from rowWeight.

Something that might help you to **restrict the characters to maximum length** called,

```
android:maxLength="5"
```

along with **ellipsize** ".." in the end.

```
android:ellipsize="end"
```

And if you want the characters to appear in **two lines**,

```
android:maxLines="2"
```

And you might have to specify the **width** of the `TextView` for each instead of `wrap_content` or `match_parent`.

```
android:layout_width="80dp"
```